# What does it mean by "it is not like she'd Fedex a 6-carat diamond"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "it is not like she'd Fedex a 6-carat diamond" mean in the following context?

> Two young ladies chat and one feels like she
>   would be proposed by her boy friend. She knew that her boy friend had
>   a lunch with his family secretly and his mom flew in from the remote
>   area. That is why she feels like she would be proposed by his
>   boyfriend. Then, her friend also tries to cheer her up, saying that
>   why else would she(his mom) have flown in from the remote area?, and
>   **"It is not like she would FedEx a 6-carat diamond**".

Comment: I don't understand "Fexdex" or "FedEx" ? Because i know FedEx is a delivery company which is related (can mean "She cannot deliver the diamond ring with FedEx") but Fexdex? I don't know.

Comment: "...she would be proposed *to* by her boyfriend..."

Comment: I am sorry it is typo. "FedEx" is correct word I should have typed.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you meant "FedEx".

The friend is suggesting that the mom is delivering the ring in person, *as opposed to* sending it by FedEx.

We sometimes use nouns that are not also verbs as verbs. It's typically informal. Here, the speaker is using the proper noun [FedEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx) as a verb to mean *ship, send, delivery by FedEx*. We can understand this from the context and from the fact that FedEx is a large delivery company.

Comment: In English, any noun can be verbed, though it weirds the language.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, and yes I am sorry it was typo. Your explanation about "the suggestion" is good for me to understand the context. Thank you so much.